# What is MergeDifferences?

Tags: documentation, built-in-symbols

My version is `13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)`.

The symbol `MergeDifferences` appears in the auto-completion
[image]

but no documentation can be found or searched on the internet.
[image]

Is this symbol relic or experimental? How to use it?

Comment: `MergeDifferences` is an option to `SequenceAlignment`. Autocompletion is not context-sensitive in this sense (although syntax highlighting is regarding unsupported/unlisted options to functions). It is probably a wise choice since options don't necessarily need to be syntactically associated with their function. The reason for lacking definition is that there's no separate documentation page for this option, which is not uncommon when options are used only by one function.

Comment: @kirma Thanks! The function `SequenceAlignment` is the first entry when searching `MergeDifferences` but I didn't look into it. You can write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MergeDifferences` is an option to `SequenceAlignment`. Autocompletion is not context-sensitive in this sense (although syntax highlighting is regarding unsupported/unlisted options to functions). It is probably a wise choice since options don't necessarily need to be syntactically associated with their function. The reason for lacking definition is that there's no separate documentation page for this option, which is not uncommon when options are used only by one function.

Frankly `?`(`Defintion`) and `??` (`Information`) could have some sort of indication for options like this that they're options associated with a function since separately documented options do have data available...